# form submitting without change form input values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, form-submit

I'm using Spring, HTML, JavaScript. I don't want to use ajax.
I have form to send form data to Spring controller.
After submitting, page is refreshed and I receive result data through model.
What I want to do is that the same value in form input same before refresh.

For example, if I text on a input "abc" before submitting, I want to see the same text "abc" on the input after refreshing page. Now I can draw a table with a calculated data after refreshing, but all of my form input data is backed to default value together.

Html page with empty table-> form submit -> Spring controller: put calculated data into model -> [After refreshing] Html page with html table with calculated data.

How can I show the same form input values after submitting?

Comment: i know nothing about Spring, but you should be able to set the `value` attributes of the form. In PHP you would do something like `<input type="text" name="something" value="<?php print $something; ?>">`

Comment: What server-side template engine are you using? Have you tried just setting the value attributes of the input fields with the model properties?

Comment: You could save the value inside a variable, and when done getting data from server add the value back inside the input with JS.

Comment: I'm using freemarker now. I haven't tried just setting the value with the model. I thought there is better way than that. I have studied only back-end. So I'm trying to study front side.. But it is too different...haha. Thanks a lot guys.